# How to change the position of long axis titles in ggtern?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

I have long axis title names in a ternary plot coded in `ggtern`. I cannot get the R and L (baseline) titles to move in (from where they are cut off). The top title looks great, but the other two do not.

I have tried to use `axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0))` and changed the positioning variables, but that didn't seem to work. So I'm at a loss as to what to do.

```
#library(tidyverse)
#library(ggtern)

confidencebreaks <- c(0.95)
x  <- runif(1000,min = 0, max = 1)
y  <- runif(1000,min = 0, max = 1)
z  <- runif(1000,min = 0, max = 1)
df <- tibble(x,y,z)

tern1 <- 
  ggtern(data = df,
         mapping = aes(x = z, y = y, z = z)
  ) +
  labs(title = "A title", 
       subtitle = "A subtitle",
       x = expression(paste(atop("Title 2", 
                                 "A long line 2 that goes on and on"))), 
       y = expression(paste(atop("Title 0", 
                                 "A long line 2 that goes on and on"))),
       z = expression(paste(atop("Title 1", 
                                 "A long line 2 that goes on and on")))
  ) + 
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=10)) 
print(tern1)
```

The code above reproduces the problem with the cut off and long axis titles. I would like to be able to shift the long axis titles for "Title 2" and "Title 1" inwards, but have not managed to do so.

Comment: well done for creating a reprex. Small suggestion, you could also use `x  <- y <- z <-  runif(1000,min = 0, max = 1)`, but that's a matter of style and not related to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to adjust the labels on ggtern, you should use tern.axis.title and the specification for which side which is R for right, L for left, and T for Top. In your question, you can adjust the labels as follows then

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(ggtern)

    confidencebreaks <- c(0.95)
    x  <- runif(1000,min = 0, max = 1)
    y  <- runif(1000,min = 0, max = 1)
    z  <- runif(1000,min = 0, max = 1)
    df <- tibble(x,y,z)

    df

    ggtern(data = df,
             mapping = aes(x = z, y = y, z = z)
      ) +
      labs(title = "A title", 
           subtitle = "A subtitle")+
           xlab("Title 2 \n A long line 2 that goes on and on")+ 
           ylab("Title 0 \n A long line 2 that goes on and on")+
           zlab("Title 1 \n A long line 2 that goes on and on")+ 
      theme(tern.axis.title.L = element_text(hjust = 0),
            tern.axis.title.R = element_text(hjust = 1))
```

This will result in a plot like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solution provided by Sebastian, the following is an alternate, depending on your particular user case:

```
library(ggtern)
x  <- runif(1000,min = 0, max = 1)
y  <- runif(1000,min = 0, max = 1)
z  <- runif(1000,min = 0, max = 1)
df = data.frame(x,y,z)
ggtern(data = df, 
       mapping = aes(x = z, y = y, z = z)) +
  labs(title = "A title",  
       subtitle = "A subtitle",
       x = "Title 2", xarrow="A long line 2 that goes on and on",
       y = "Title 0", yarrow="A long line 0 that goes on and on",
       z = "Title 1", zarrow="A long line 1 that goes on and on"
  ) + 
  theme_showarrows()
```

[image: Result]